# Increment and decrements item quantity based on id (S.NO)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have an app in which allows the user to increment or decrement the in-stock quantity of an item.  When I click an increment or decrement button, *all* the items are changed at once.  Only the item from the clicked row should get changed.  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

**html code**

```
  <ion-content class="item"> 

  <ion-list *ngIf="showList">
      <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
        {{ item }}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

  <ion-list>
    <div class="header">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-row >
          <ion-col width-15>SNo</ion-col>
          <ion-col width-25>PartNo</ion-col>
          <ion-col width-25>Qty</ion-col>
          <ion-col width-15>Price</ion-col>
          <ion-col width-20>Action</ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-item>
    </div>

    <div class="list">
        <ion-item *ngFor="let list of quickOrder; let i = index">
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col width-15>{{list.SNo}}</ion-col>
            <ion-col width-25>{{list.PartNo}}</ion-col>
            <ion-col width-25 class="add">
            <button clear (click)="incrementQty()"><ion-icon name="add-circle" ></ion-icon></button>{{qty}}
            <button clear (click)="decrementQty()"><ion-icon name="remove-circle" ></ion-icon></button>
          </ion-col>
            <ion-col width-15>{{list.Price}}</ion-col>
            <ion-col width-20><button clear (click)="delete(i)"><ion-icon name="close-circle"></ion-icon></button></ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-item>
    </div>
  </ion-list>

    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>    

    <div class="addtocart">
      <center><button padding (click)="addToCart();">Add to Cart</button></center>
    </div>      
</ion-content>
```

**.ts file**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Slides} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/titlepage/titlepage.html',
})
export class titlePage {
  qty:any;
  constructor(private nav: NavController) {
    this.qty = 1;
  }

  // increment product qty
  incrementQty() {
    console.log(this.qty+1);
    this.qty += 1;
  }

  // decrement product qty
  decrementQty() {
    if(this.qty-1 < 1 ){
      this.qty = 1
      console.log('1->'+this.qty);
    }else{
      this.qty -= 1;
      console.log('2->'+this.qty);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add an actual question to your post

Comment: Clarified the wording, removed redundancies, and corrected spelling errors.

Answer (score 0):

Since the list is an array of items, the quantity of the items should be present in the list as well. Having only one quantity attribute means it impacts the entire list.

I believe the quick order array looks something like this now

```
[{SNo: 1, PartNo: S23456, Price: 2500}, {...}, ...]
```

One way of solving this would be to have a quantity attribute for each item so the quickOrder array looks like

```
[{SNo: 1, PartNo: S23456, Price: 2500, qty: 3}, {...}, ...].
```

And the increment and decrement functions also take the index similar to the delete function. The increment function is shown below

```
incrementQty(index: number) {
    this.quickOrder[index].qty += 1;
}
```

A better option would be to construct a separate quickOrderItem component which contains its own increment and decrement functions and use the current component as a container for it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let product of cart; let index=index">

<strong> ₹ {{ item_qty *  product.price  }}</strong>

<ion-card>


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {  NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
selector: 'page-cart',
templateUrl: 'cart.html',
})
export class CartPage implements OnInit {

item_qty:any;

constructor()
{this.item_qty=1;}

// increment item 
inc(){
this.item_qty += 1;
console.log(this.item_qty + 1);
}

//decrements item

dec(){
if(this.item_qty-1 < 1){
this.item_qty = 1;
console.log('item_1->' + this.item_qty)
}
else{
this.item_qty -= 1;
console.log('item_2->' + this.item_qty);
}
}

}
```